# Cannot redeclare class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider - Laravel 4.2

Tags: class, laravel, composer-php

In my Laravel 4.2 project, when I run "php artisan migrate" or "composer install", I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class
>   Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider in .../bootstrap/compiled.php on
>   line 2981

Any ideas?

Comment: try `composer clear-compiled` first

Comment: I get 'Command "clear-compiled" is not defined.'

Comment: apologies, it is `php artisan clear compiled`

Comment: I get the same error: "Cannot redeclare class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider" when I try this.

Comment: Remove the most recent service providers you added. See if the error goes away. It looks like you might have copied the base service provider boilerplate into your own. Remove the last service providers you added and see if you can migrate

Comment: Do you mean by deleting the vendors directory? This is what I tried, and I then I re-ran "composer update". After the packages are downloaded, I get the same error again. I still continue to get the error when I run other commands like "composer install".